# ServiceStack.Redis stores empty object in the cache

Tags: c#, caching, redis, servicestack, redisclient

I'm trying to implement a redis cache for my c# project. I used **redisClient** which is good to store normal datatypes like int and strings but not for storing objects. Then I moved to **RedisTypedClient** which should store my object in redis but it **stores an empty object**. And when i try to retrieve that object, it creates a new object and returns that.

Here's my test code which i'm trying to get to work but it's not working.

```
internal class Test
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public string s;

    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + "  " + b + "  " + s);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
        {
            var t = new List<Test>();

            t.Add(new Test {a = 1, b = 2});
            t.Add(new Test {a = 3, b = 4});

            var key = "e";

            var rtest = redisClient.As<Test>();

            rtest.Store(t[0]).show();

            Console.WriteLine(t[0].GetId());
            var q = rtest.GetById(t[0].GetId());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I have also tried using redis list.

```
IRedisList<Test> tl = rtest.Lists["testl"];
tl.Add(new Test { a = 1, b = 2 }); 
tl.Add(new Test { a = 3, b = 4 });
var rlist = rtest.Lists["testl"];
```

But the same thing happens in this case also. It stores empty objects.

I'm new to redis on windows and it may be possible that I'm making some mistake. But I can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that ServiceStack is a commercially-supported product. See the [free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) on servicestack.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) Serializer only stores **public properties** so you need to convert the **fields** in your class you want serialized into properties, e.g:

```
internal class Test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }

    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + "  " + b + "  " + s);
    }
}
```

Or you can change the text serializer to also serialize **public fields** with:

```
JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```